# Install two gcc compiler on the same machine

Tags: redhat, gcc

My question is simple, is it possible to install two different version of gcc on the same red hat machine.

For example : gcc3.4 and gcc4, on red hat 6 ?

Comment: Yes. For one method, have a look at https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at software collections (SCL). You probably want to take a look at the [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/products/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/Developer/#dts=&dev-page=6) SCL.